# Macintosh and Windows pull-down menus

Tags: windows, macos, menu

Anyone has any idea why is accessing Macintosh pull-down menus (on the screen) are much faster than accessing Windows pull-down menus (on the window)?

Answer (score 3):

The MacOS menu bar is at the top of the screen. This makes them essentially infinitely tall. So as a target, they're very easy to hit. In Windows, the menus are within a window, so if you over-shoot with the mouse, you miss the target area and don't open the menu. One of the design principles they used in designing the Macintosh was [Fitts's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law) - essentially the larger the target is, the easier it is to acquire.

Comment: While I understand their reasoning, to me task locality seems more important. After months of working with Windows and Mac simultaneously, I still find it irritating to have to go all the way up on the screen to trigger an action inside the window.